# Blender 3.5: Rig Main Properties of Rigify Rig not shown in N-Panel after generating rig with Human Generator

Tags: blender

I made a character with Human Generator 4 Beta and rigged it with the rigify function that comes with Human Generator. Everything works fine. The issue: the Main Rig Properties menu is not shown in the Rigify Tab in the N-panel.
My Blender version is 3.5. OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Anybody has any ideas how to fix this?
Many thanks,
Marie

Tried to find an answer via Google and checked the Blender documentation if anything had changed in 3.5.